# getMonth return wrong Values_NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this code that search in the mongoDB and get all the birthday's date and for each birthday Date it extract the month from it , the code works perfectly for extracting the dates but the problem when I apply `getMonth()` it returns wrong value

for ex:  `today is 09/05/2020` when I apply `getMonth()` it returns `8` and I don't know why

the code that I'm using is  below

```
User.find({}).lean(true).exec((err, users) => {
                let toBirth = [];


                for (let i =0 ; i < users.length; i++) { 
        const dt = datetime.create();
        dt.offsetInDays(0);
        const formatted = dt.format('m');
        const newFormatted = users[i].birthDay// the date here should be 09/05/2020
        const month = newFormatted.getMonth();
        console.log(month); // the output here is 8 it must be 5 and sometimes I get this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'getMonth' of undefined
           // console.log(formatted)
            if(month === formatted) {
                toBirth.push({user: users[i].userName, birthDay: users[i].birthDay});
            }
        }
           console.log(toBirth);
            });   
    }
```

the image of the  `console.log(month)` is below

[image]

another error that I get is below

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getMonth' of undefined
```

Comment: console `newFormatted`

Comment: @nafeo I updated my question cause I changed `const newFormatted = users[i].birthDay`  the output  is  09/05/2020

Comment: there should be multiple outputs.
check `newFormatted` and `month` respectively

Comment: I was looking for something like this saved my day

Comment: @nafeo now after the change mentionned above `console.log(newFormatted) = 09/05/2020` but `the console.log(month) is error TypeError: Cannot read property 'getMonth' of undefined`

Comment: There is no `getMonth` function in `node-datetime` object.

Comment: Do a `console.dir(newFormatted)` and tell me the result.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty the outout is here https://ibb.co/6skxCPm,,,, also the birthday model is string

Comment: I did `console.log(typeof(newFormatted))` and return string

Comment: So why do you expect a string will have a `getMonth` function?

Comment: I know my fault didn't pay attention is there something  that I need to do to get that month ... only month format

Comment: I think we need to convert the string to an ISODate, THEN get the month. Else, this date would never work properly, as we're not dealing with dataType Date.

Comment: I tried this function `const month = new Date(newFormatted).toISOString()` and the output is different than `09/05/2020` it is like this `2020-09-04T22:00:00.000Z`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comment `birthDay` is string. So you need to basically convert it to Date.

The most convenient solution will be to use [`momentjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) the most popular datetime library by many miles.

```
const date = moment('09/05/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
date.month()
```

> **Note: Months are zero indexed, so January is month 0.**

Here is the [doc](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/),
But you can split the string like and use the second index as well: `birthDay.split('/')[1]`

Note:
Also to get current month you can just use `const m = moment().month()`

Comment: I tired the provided solution  `const date = moment(newFormatted, 'DD-MM-YYYY').month();`and this the output  https://ibb.co/rcKBk62   it is like returning month -1

Comment: both solution and note are returning the same value which is `4` see below `const date = moment(newFormatted, 'DD-MM-YYYY').month();
        const m = moment().month()
      console.dir(newFormatted)
      console.log((date))
      console.log(m)`   the output is here https://ibb.co/7zwNBY5

Comment: yes that is correct. In moment months are zero indexed. You can see in the docs that's why I added the doc link.

Comment: Also i said i had a typo. the format will be `DD/MM/YYYY` not dd-mm-yyyy. Please check out the answer carefully.